# What technology is used for Visual Studio SDK window?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

What library is used to create a window form like below?

It certainly does not look/feel/acts like a typical windows forms app.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spy++ says it's a Windows Forms app, with a Web Browser control embedded for the bottom portion (window 004109AA, bottom). The tabs too are a Windows Forms control (window 006B0D26, 5th from top).

[spy++ http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/7308/spyf.png](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/7308/spyf.png)

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't know where I could find that SDK program.

Comment: If you have visual studio installed, it should be under C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools.

Comment: It feels like I found a pot of gold... Spy++.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spy++ you can see what it is based off of the class name of the window. It looks like it could be WPF or HTML.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to "catch fish" but I do not have spy++ installed